# Azure Active Directory Authentication and SharePoint CSOM

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, openid, csom

I have a web application, which connects to SharePoint (customer tenant) to create sites & various List.

To access the customers Sharepoint environment, I used `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` which prompts user for AAD creditinals and then the various options for which user wants to provide access ( This App and various API access needed is configured in AAD - when allowing access to "O365 SharePoint Online"

Using `OpenIdConnectAutheticationOption`, on AuthorizationCode Received the code is used to get "AccessToken".
Using this "AccessToken" to get clientContext gives error:

> "401 - Not authorized"

How one can get the required token which allows CSOM operation?

The code used from -
[Active Directory Dot net Webapp Multitenant](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect)

In the controller OnboardingController, Processcode function, after getting AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync following code is used -

```
        string siteUrl = "https://svtestsite.sharepoint.com/sites/powerapps";
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        ctx.ExecutingWebRequest +=
                     delegate(object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
                     {
webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] =
                                           "Bearer " + result.AccessToken; // accessToken;
               };
    ctx.Load(ctx.Web, p => p.Title);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(siteUrl);
    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);
```

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to acquire the Access Token and how you're associating it with ClientContext..

Comment: Please check the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet that you've shared, which sets bearer token for request Authorization header looks fine to me.

```
ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += 
                         delegate(object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
                         {
    webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] =
                                               "Bearer " + result.AccessToken; // accessToken;
                   };
```

So your issue could be with either the token itself or some permissions missing for app/users. Here are a few things that you should check:

1. Required permissions for your App Registered in Azure AD. Make sure the app has permissions for "Office 365 SharePoint Online". Which exact permissions depends on your requirements/use cases, but at least 1 should be there. Also, you should go through with the consent flow either using "Grant Permissions" button or as part of Onboarding flow for the tenant.

   [image]
2. Check which "Resource" has the token been acquired for.

   At least the sample code link you mention in your question ([Active Directory Dot net Webapp Multitenant](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect)) mentions the resource as `"https://graph.windows.net"`.

   Make sure you have changed that to your SharePoint site collection URL.. something like  `"https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/"`.

   Do try with including/excluding the `/` at the end of this URL. I've seen issues just because of that as well, although not sure if yours is related.
3. If above points don't work, it would be worthwhile to examine the access token you are sending to SharePoint in a tool like https://jwt.io or https://jwt.ms Especially, look for:

   **"aud" claim**, which tells about the intended audience for which this token was issued. It should be your SharePoint URL. If it's not that can be causing the issue.

   **"tid" claim**, to see that token is from correct Azure AD tenant. It will be GUID.

   and other claims in token, to see if anything suspicious pops out.
4. Obvious one, but if you're using delegated permissions, then check that the user has appropriate permissions in SharePoint site collection.

Comment: @user1872862 did any of the suggestions work or are you still facing issues?